# TextChanged event does not fire when 2nd modification equals the original value

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, user-controls, viewstate

I have a _TextChanged event which works properly except in a specific circumstance which can be replicated as follows:

1. User modifies text (event fires correctly)
2. User modifies text again to match the original value (event doesn't fire)

I can get the _TextChanged event to work on my development box by turning on Viewstate for the update panel on the ascx page, but when I move it to the server I get an error that the viewstate failed if I switch user controls and then switch back to that page.  The controls which go inside the update panel are build dynamically in code behind and are rebuilt with each postback -- this works for every other postback so I don't think the issue is with the controls.

Additionally, turning on viewstate makes the page run dreadfully slow anyway, so this would not be an ideal fix.

Finally, the _TextChanged event works for all changes *except* when reverting back to the original value.

Can anyone tell me why the event doesn't fire in that specific circumstance, and how to address the problem?

Text box creation in code behind:

```
 TextBox annualHoursTextBox = new TextBox();
 annualHoursTextBox.ID = string.Format("bundle{0}_annualHoursTextBox{1}", bundle.BundleNbr, parentItem.LaborItemNbr);
 annualHoursTextBox.CssClass = "";
 annualHoursTextBox.Columns = 4;
 annualHoursTextBox.Text = childItem == null ? string.Empty : childItem.FTEHours.ToString("F0");
 annualHoursTextBox.AutoPostBack = true;
 annualHoursTextBox.TextChanged += new EventHandler(annualHoursTextBox_TextChanged);

 AsyncPostBackTrigger AHtrigger = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();
 AHtrigger.ControlID = annualHoursTextBox.UniqueID;
 AHtrigger.EventName = "TextChanged";
 upPricingSheet.Triggers.Add(AHtrigger);

 //snip

 //add some attributes for reference on the events
 annualHoursTextBox.Attributes["othercontrol"] = tasksPerYearTextBox.UniqueID;
 annualHoursTextBox.Attributes["nextcontrol"] = benefitsTextBox.UniqueID;
 annualHoursTextBox.Attributes["targetTBcontrol"] = taskTimeTextBox.UniqueID;
 annualHoursTextBox.Attributes["targetDDLcontrol"] = taskTimeUOMDropDown.UniqueID;
```

Event Handler:

```
protected void annualHoursTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox ah = sender as TextBox;
    TextBox other = Page.FindControl(ah.Attributes["othercontrol"]) as TextBox;

    if ((!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ah.Text)) && (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(other.Text))) 
    {
        TextBox next = Page.FindControl(ah.Attributes["nextcontrol"]) as TextBox;
        TextBox targetTB = Page.FindControl(ah.Attributes["targetTBcontrol"]) as TextBox;
        DropDownList ddl = Page.FindControl(ah.Attributes["targetDDLcontrol"]) as DropDownList;
        Double TasksPerSecond;

        TasksPerSecond = CalculateTimePerTask(ah.Text, other.Text);
        string TimeUnit;
        double Time;

        if (TasksPerSecond < 60)
        {
            TimeUnit = "Seconds";
            Time = TasksPerSecond;
        }
        else if (TasksPerSecond < 3600)
        {
            TimeUnit = "Minutes";
            Time = (TasksPerSecond / 60);
        }
        else
        {
            TimeUnit = "Hours";
            Time = (TasksPerSecond / 60 / 60);
        }

        //Enter the time in the appropriate textbox
        targetTB.Text = Time.ToString("F2");

        //select the appropriate item from the ddl
        ListItem i = ddl.Items.FindByText(TimeUnit);

        if (i != null)
        {
            ddl.SelectedItem.Selected = false;
            i.Selected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

ASPX Page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master"
AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Solution.aspx.cs" Inherits="Solution" %>

<%@ Register Src="fragments/solutionRecommended.ascx" TagName="solutionRecommended"
TagPrefix="uc1" %>
<%@ Register Src="fragments/solutionPricingSheet.ascx" TagName="solutionPricingSheet"
TagPrefix="uc2" %>
<%@ Register Src="fragments/solutionSuggested.ascx" TagName="solutionSuggested" TagPrefix="uc3" %>
<%@ Register Src="fragments/solutionSummary.ascx" TagName="solutionSummary" TagPrefix="uc4" %>
<%@ Register Src="fragments/ucItemFilterSearch.ascx" TagName="ucItemFilterSearch"
TagPrefix="uc5" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addItemToBundle(postUrl, redirectUrl) {
        $.post(postUrl);
        window.location = redirectUrl;
        //  window.location = url;
    }

</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfStepNbr" runat="server" />
<asp:Panel ID="pnlStepMessage" runat="server" Visible="false" CssClass="padding10">
    <h3 class="placeholder">
        <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" /></h3>
</asp:Panel>
<div class='elev8form' id="mainDiv" runat="server">
    <h3 class='header'>
        Solutions</h3>
    <div id="tabs">
        <div class='tab'>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbSuggested" runat="server" Text="Select Items" data-step="1"
                OnClick="lbTab_Click" CausesValidation="false"></asp:LinkButton>
        </div>
        <div class='tab'>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbPricing" runat="server" Text="Pricing Worksheet" data-step="2"
                OnClick="lbTab_Click" ></asp:LinkButton>
        </div>
        <div class='tab'>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbRecommendedSolutions" runat="server" Text="Recommended Solutions"
                data-step="3" OnClick="lbTab_Click" CausesValidation="false"></asp:LinkButton>
        </div>
        <div class='tab'>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbSummary" runat="server" Text="Solutions Summary" data-step="4"
                OnClick="lbTab_Click" CausesValidation="false"></asp:LinkButton>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="solutions-body">
        <asp:MultiView ID="mltSolution" runat="server">
            <asp:View ID="viewSuggested" runat="server">
                <uc3:solutionSuggested ID="solutionSuggested1" runat="server" RedirectUrl="~/portal/elev8/solution.aspx" />
            </asp:View>
            <asp:View ID="viewPricing" runat="server">
                <uc2:solutionPricingSheet ID="solutionPricingSheet1" runat="server" />
            </asp:View>
            <asp:View ID="viewRecommended" runat="server">
                <uc1:solutionRecommended ID="solutionRecommended1" runat="server" />
            </asp:View>
            <asp:View ID="viewSummary" runat="server">
                <p style="font-size: 14px;">
                    Text here 
                </p>
                <uc4:solutionSummary ID="solutionSummary1" runat="server" />
            </asp:View>
        </asp:MultiView>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad() {
        $(function () {

            var maxChannelHeight;

            var items = $('.channel');

            for (var counter = 0; counter < items.length; counter++) {
                var channel = items[counter];

                var channelHeight = $(channel).height();

                maxChannelHeight = maxChannelHeight > channelHeight ? maxChannelHeight : channelHeight;
            }

            $('.channel').height(maxChannelHeight);

            $("#priceing-sheet-save-button *").click(function () {
                window.scrollTo(0, 0);

            });
        });
    }

</script>
```

ASCX Page:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="solutionPricingSheet.ascx.cs"
Inherits="solutionPricingSheet" %>

<asp:UpdateProgress ID="upProgressRecSolution" runat='server' AssociatedUpdatePanelID="upPricingSheet">
<ProgressTemplate>
    <div style="position: absolute; z-index: 2000; left: 45%; display: inline; width: 100px;"
        class="elev8form">
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat='server' ImageUrl="~/portal/img/ajax-loader-big.gif" />
    </div>
</ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
<div id="pricing-sheet-wrapper">
<p class='left'>
    More text</p>
<asp:Panel ID="pnlSaveMessage" runat="server" Visible="false" CssClass="save-message">
    <span>Item prices saved</span>
</asp:Panel>
<div class='export'>
    <span class='bigbutton'>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnExport" runat='server' Text="Export to Excel" OnClick="btnExport_Click" />
    </span>
</div>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upPricingSheet" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div id="pricing-sheet">        
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phContent" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="opportunityPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
            <div class='save export'>
                <div>
                    <div id="pageValidationError" class="validationMessage">
                       * Changes not saved. Review all entries for validation messages. Required fields marked with an asterisk.
                    </div>
                </div>
                <%--<asp:HiddenField ID="hf" runat="server" value="0" />--%>
                <center>
                    <span id="priceing-sheet-save-button">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save All Prices" SkinID="redbutton"
                        OnClick="btnSave_Click" CausesValidation="true" />
                    </span>
                </center>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function pageLoad() {

                $("#tabs .tab a").click(function () {
                    $("#<%= btnSave.ClientID%>").click();
                });
            }
        </script>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.validationMessage').hide();

    $('#<%= btnSave.ClientID %>').click(function () {
        if (Page_IsValid == false) {
            $('.validationMessage').show();
            return false;
        }
    });

    $('input[type=text]').blur(function () {
        if (Page_IsValid == false) {
            $('.validationMessage').show();
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $('.validationMessage').hide();
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I am not place -1 as you are new member, but your question is  not helping at all. You have throw some big code that is not even contain the part that you say have problem, or at least I can not locate it. I spend a lot of time, and still can not find where is the problem, in witch line. Please show only the part of your code have this problem, and focus to the real issue. I think that you do not even know what this code do. The `TextChanged` is not exist on your code at all.

Comment: @Aristos -- I am aware I did not post the _TextChanged event because it works.  It is only under the precise circumstance I outlined above that it does not work, so the error is somewhere else.  But I added to the original post just for verification.

Comment: And where is attached ? the annualHours_textchanged can not find it.

Comment: Do you mean where the textbox is created?  I added that portion of code.  It occurs in a sub called by Page_Load.

Comment: don't forget to accept an answer if it helped you, as a basic courtesy towards others...

Comment: Not yet, POcHa.  When I get a break I will tear apart the page and recreate it to see if I can find the problem, but this works perfectly on one page and not on the other.  If all else fails I will try the OnBlur event, although my preference would be not to run the event even when the text hasn't changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the intended behavior - the event is called `OnTextChanged` (different from original) not `OnTextTyped` (any text entered), for that you would have to handle this event (which triggers even if nothing at all is entered):

`OnBlur="__doPostBack(this.id, '');"`

**UPDATE:** its pretty simple actually, since you are using ajax, your textbox's `.defaultValue`  is not changing between postbacks, only the `.value` is - so either use `OnBlur` as I told you, or on every postback change the `.defaultValue` to `.value` in javascript: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_defaultvalue.asp

or just place the textbox in the `UpdatePanel`, and it will take care of it self on its own...

**UPDATE 2:** First off, nowhere in your code is the textbox shown to be inside an `UpdatePanel', and secondly, you have 3 choices:

a) For `OnBlur` method to work, remove `AutoPostBack` property (it is the client side `OnChange` event), but keep the `OnTextChanged` event (it is server side).

b) For `ViewState` method to work, set `ViewStateMode="Enabled"` on the textbox, and make sure you are using `ViewStateMode="Disabled"` on its containers - and not `EnableViewState="False"`.

c) javascript `.defaultValue` method...

Comment: Thanks, but the text has changed.  The user is not going from "foo" to "foo" but rather from "foo" to "bar", "bar" to "stuff" and then "stuff" to "foo" -- the event runs each and every time as it should -- until the user goes back to "foo".  An nearly identical method works on another page; just not on this one.

Comment: @NicoleCastle the text has, but the value attribute has **not**, I updated the answer with clarifications for you...

Comment: It already *is* in an update panel -- but as mentioned above viewstate is turned off and can't be turned on.  We were unable to get the OnBlur event to fire correctly either.  I'm going to try the other option you mentioned.

Comment: The update panel is about line 23 of the ASCX file above.  I tried A) B) and C) on Friday.  No progress on any of them; something in the page life cycle is clearing out the data.  I also tried stashing values in hidden fields outside the update panel but they got cleared out as well.  This bug is obscure enough from a user standpoint that we are bumping it into the backlog and moving on.  Whenever I do revisit the issue I will be looking at it from a different direction: why I get viewstate errors on the server but not in development.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer, though, because all three of these items are solutions that *should* work, and I really appreciate your help!